# Vertical align bottom UL inside DIV

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a `div` with `height:40px;` and an `ul` with `line-height:28px;`. I would like to place the ul to the bottom, inside the div. I tried `vertical-align:bottom;`, but it doesn't help.

My other idea is the top margin, but if it's possible with vertical-align, I'll choose that.

My demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YpEd7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/25VV5/1/ this will not work?

Comment: `margin:12px 0 0 0;` Would this not work as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add line height to the container. Once you have line-height of 40px on the container, the vertical align bottom will align it to the bottom since your container is also 40px tall. It wasn't working before since the line-height of the container was less than 40px so the ul did align to the bottom of the default line-height

http://jsfiddle.net/YpEd7/2/

```
#container {
    background:gray;
    height:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same i posted in comment above^

```
#container {
    background:gray;
    height:40px;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25VV5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to mix vertical-align to line-height in order to have this happen: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YpEd7/1/)**

```
#container {
    background:gray;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;/* equal to height of container */
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:bottom;/* fine since i'm inline-block */
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:1em;
}

ul li {
    line-height:28px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Why the line-height:1em is required for ul?

Comment: Note , that defaut value for vertical-align is baseline, so if you remove it , your li will stand on the middle of 40px height

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai to reset line-height inside li else, it is 40px too :)

Comment: i just took out that and tested it. Works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Please stop perpetuating the line-height hack for vertical alignment. Vertical alignment only works when there is a sibling to reference.

If you only have one element that you want vertically aligned, you must first wrap it in an element with a defined height (can be %). Then you place the following class onto the container element.

### CSS

```
.VAlignHelper:after {
    content:'';
    font-size:0;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="container" class="VAlignHelper">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/jmdrury/YpEd7/3/

Comment: vertical-align + line-height for text and inline-boxes work fine, it is what it is meant for, move an element from its' base line whithin text or among other inline-boxes.It sets a min-height too to the element if none set in CSS. you can play with this http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rmxpo to find out interaction with elements and baseline/line-height ;)

Comment: Line height is absolutely not designed for aligning elements. It is designed to provide the ability to change the spacing between line box elements such as 'p'.  For example, making a block of text double spaced. You can confirm this by reviewing the specs online on Mozilla or W3.

Comment: This is what it is about here, set an inline-box down the bottom. ....... here we have an element and one line/inline-box. .....  That you set a line-height or not, tall element will stretch it. This is what your pseudo element is doing, stretching the line-height up to 40px, but only on the line it will stands. http://jsfiddle.net/YpEd7/4/ my answer did not use pseudo because you did & cause i was called the *master of pseudo-elements* in another question  (do i use them too much ? :) ). I  thought usefull to remind how line-height works and what it involves.